# What does --save-dev mean in npm install grunt --save-dev?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, npm

I've just started using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/). It is pretty hard to set up and I am at the point of creating a `package.json` file.

Following this [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130918061104/http://www.codingcolor.com/javascript/setting-up-a-boilerplate-gruntfile-js/), it says there are 3 ways to create a `package.json` file.

The first is to do `npm install grunt --save-dev`

> The first method is to navigate to the project directory via command-line(Terminal) and install grunt using npm : *sudo npm install grunt –save-dev*. After the install, you can use [grunt-init](https://web.archive.org/web/20130918061104/http://gruntjs.com/project-scaffolding) task to automatically generate a project-specific package.json file.

**But what does `--save-dev` mean?** I tried looking but it ends in vain.

Comment: I think I manage to find some answers.
http://gruntjs.com/getting-started
 - 
https://npmjs.org/doc/json.html#devDependencies

Comment: tutorial link broken

Comment: @SteveC Changed tutorial link to archive.org and quoted the relevant portion

Comment: And no wonder there was confusion: the original tutorial used an [en-dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), not a double hyphen`--` (i.e. `–save-dev`, not `--save-dev`).

Answer (score 343, accepted):

> --save-dev: Package will appear in your devDependencies.

According to the [npm install docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install).

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.

In other words, when you run `npm install`, your project's devDependencies will be installed, but the devDependencies for any packages that your app depends on will not be installed; further, other apps having your app as a dependency need not install your devDependencies. Such modules should only be needed when developing the app (eg grunt, mocha etc).

According to the [package.json docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#devdependencies)

#### Edit: Attempt at visualising what `npm install` does:

- yourproject

  - dependency installed

    - dependency installed

      - dependency installed
      - *<s>devDependency NOT installed</s>*
    - *<s>devDependency NOT installed</s>*
  - **devDependency installed**

    - dependency installed
    - *<s>devDependency NOT installed</s>*

Comment: by default it wont install with dev dependencies but how i install with then? ```npm install --dev``` flag?

Comment: @stanzheng I'm not sure what you need to know. If you're in a project and run `npm install`, the project's devDependencies will also be installed. You don't want a dependency's devDependencies installed. If you want to develop on an npm package, you'd `git clone xxx` that project, and run `npm install` in it.

Comment: "devDependencies for your app's dependencies will not be installed when you run npm install" is incorrect. If I have a package.json and it only contains "devDependencies" with my npm packages, and I then type "npm install," those "devDependecies" get installed.

Comment: @core that's exactly what i mean. You devDependencies gets installed. The devDependencies of the installed packages does not in turn get installed. I agree it's not completely clearly worded though; maybe you could suggest a better way to phrase it?

Comment: @core I added a visualisation; does that help?

Comment: I tried to understand and I didn't. Then I tried to understand the visualization and I didn't. What does each bullet-point item mean? A folder? What the strikethrough item mean? A non-existing directory? If that is true, how can you list exhaustively *non-existing* things?

Comment: @RafaelEyng It's a tree of the dependencies in your project (package.json). The **bold** shows that any devDependency that _you_ have specified in package.json are installed. The strikethrough shows that any devDependency that the packages in your package.json in turn have specified in their own package.json are not installed.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren From what you said, seems that npm installs recursively the dependencies going only 1 level down when is devDependencies (is that right)?

Comment: @RafaelEyng yes, only one level of devDependencies are installed.

Comment: To clarify, if `npm install` is run in your project, all devDependencies in package.json will be installed, but if you package your project as a new npm package and publish it, when somebody else installs your package with npm install, the devDependencies will not be installed on their system. Is that right? @stanzheng or you can run npm install --production to install everything in package.json except the dev dependencies

Answer (score 111):

There are (at least) two types of package dependencies you can indicate in your package.json files:

1. Those packages that are required in order to *use* your module are listed under the "dependencies" property. Using npm you can add those dependencies to your package.json file this way:

   ```
   npm install --save packageName
   ```
2. Those packages required in order to help *develop* your module are listed under the "devDependencies" property. These packages are not necessary for others to use the module, but if they want to help develop the module, these packages will be needed. Using npm you can add those devDependencies to your package.json file this way:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev packageName
   ```

Answer (score 36):

To add on to Andreas' answer, you can install only the dependencies by using:

```
npm install --production
```

Answer (score 14):

When you use the parameter "--save" your dependency will go inside the #1 below in package.json. When you use the parameter "--save-dev" your dependency will go inside the #2 below in package.json.

#1. "dependencies": these packages are required by your application in production.

#2. "devDependencies": these packages are only needed for development and testing

Comment: This is the clearest simplest explanation in English.

Answer (score 7):

Documentation from npm for `npm install <package-name> --save` and `npm install <package-name> --save-dev` can be found here:

https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/using-a-package.json#the-save-and-save-dev-install-flags

A `package.json` file declares metadata about the module you are developing. Both aforementioned commands modify this `package.json` file. `--save` will declare the installed package (in this case, `grunt`) as a dependency for your module; `--save-dev` will declare it as a dependency for development of your module.

Ask yourself: will the installed package be required for use of my module, or will it only be required for developing it?

Answer (score 5):

For me the first answer appears a bit confusing, so to make it short and clean:

`npm install <package_name>` saves any specified packages into dependencies by **default**. Additionally, you can control where and how they get saved with some additional flags:

`npm install <package_name> --no-save` Prevents saving to dependencies.

`npm install <package_name> ---save-dev` updates the `devDependencies` in your package.  These are only used for local testing and development.

You can read more at [in the dcu](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)

Answer (score 3):

**–save**

The package installed is core dependency.

**–save-dev**

The package installed is not a core rather development dependency.

Answer (score 2):

#### Use only when developing

- `--save-dev` means omit in production environments, use only in development environments (smaller, and probably faster).