# What is the difference between --save and --save-dev?

Tags: node.js, npm, save, package

What is the difference between:

```
npm install [package_name]
```

and:

```
npm install [package_name] --save
```

and:

```
npm install [package_name] --save-dev
```

What does this mean? And what is really the effect of `--save` and `-dev` keywords?

Comment: yeah I am confused about this - if you use continuous integration like Jenkins, does Jenkins know to use the devDependencies modules for running tests? I assume so but it's not super obvious.

Comment: perhaps edit the question to also say, what is the functional difference between dependencies and devDependencies?

Comment: Packages installed via the --save-dev option are not re-installed when the user executes `npm install --production`.  That's the operational difference (see [https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) for more info).

Comment: also if you set environment variable `NODE_ENV` to production, then just  `npm install` automatically excludes development packages.

Comment: The real problem is that this is just an unclear distinction that could be improved on the node / npm side. There is no noticable difference between --save and --save-dev when developing. To take the `moment.js` example: when running webpack, the `moment` code is taken from `node_modules` and included in the project. In this sense there is no difference with `typescript` which is also needed when running webpack.

Answer (score 995, accepted):

The difference between `--save` and `--save-dev` may not be immediately noticeable if you have tried them both on your own projects. So here are a few examples...

Let's say you were building an app that used the **[moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment)** package to parse and display dates. Your app is a scheduler so it really needs this package to run, as in: **cannot run without it**. In this case you would use

```
npm install moment --save
```

This would create a new value in your package.json

```
"dependencies": {
   ...
   "moment": "^2.17.1"
}
```

When you are developing, it really helps to use tools such as test suites and may need [jasmine-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine-core) and [karma](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma). In this case you would use

```
npm install jasmine-core --save-dev
npm install karma --save-dev
```

This would also create a new value in your package.json

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "karma": "^1.4.1",
}
```

You do **not need** the test suite to run the app in its normal state, so it is a `--save-dev` type dependency, nothing more. You can see how if you do not understand what is really happening, it is a bit hard to imagine.

Taken directly from NPM docs [docs#dependencies](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#dependencies)

> **Dependencies**
>
> Dependencies are specified in a simple object that maps a package name
> to a version range. The version range is a string that has one or
> more space-separated descriptors. Dependencies can also be identified
> with a tarball or git URL.
>
> **Please do not put test harnesses or transpilers in your dependencies
> object. See devDependencies**, below.

Even in the docs, it asks you to use `--save-dev` for modules such as test harnesses.

Comment: IMO, i think the 'save' keyword is a problem.
Why don't they make -dev flag for develop and -deploy for deployment. It make sense than 'save' keyword.

Comment: Why doesn't the package just know (decide) if it's a release package or a dev package and --save be used for both. Seems odd to make the installing user decide this, when the package developer creates the intent.

Comment: CodeGrue, if you use jQuery only for testing React components it would go in save-dev, but you may not actually use it to build your main project. Yes, this is possible. So why would the packager know what you are doing with it?

Comment: Much clearer. I'm an embedded guy learning Bootstra + Node.js workflow for the first time.  It's not obvious what the difference is off the cuff.

Comment: it's still not quite clear: if I use a bundler (webpack) and sources don't work by themselves, do I have to save bundler as save or save-dev? Examples I've seen suggest that usually save-dev is used, but it's not quite clear why

Comment: @YakovL save-dev means the packages are not installed when somebody else installs your package as their dependency. Packages that are only used to run scripts such as start/build will not be needed in that case, so they're put in dev-dependencies. If you're working on a web app and not on a package for use by others, you probably shouldn't worry about it at all.

Comment: Good answer. Apart from the technical part, we also need a "theory" one, a "why" for it.

Comment: This is exactly the answer for the remaining questions asked in this page! Focused, good example. Thank you.

Comment: the author doesn't know how to choose keywords properly.. welcome to open source

Comment: Neither this, nor any other answer here, mentions the difference between a regular `npm install` and a `npm install --save`

Comment: @adham there is no difference, --save is default.

Answer (score 830):

- `--save-dev` is used to save the package for development purpose.
  Example: unit tests, minification..
- `--save` is used to save the
  package required for the application to run.

Comment: How are they different? When would I use one vs the other? 
Can I still use it the package in production if it is under --save-dev?

Comment: The answer succinctly answers your first two questions. The answer to the last question, "Can I still use the package in production if it is under --save-dev," is "no." While it's certainly _possible_ to do this, it is not intended.

Comment: Shorthand versions: `-D` is short for `--save-dev` and `-S` is short for `--save`

Comment: keyword here is "package" if your developing a web app, either will suffice.

Comment: Perfect examples of this are: "npm install grunt --save-dev", & "npm install typescript --save-dev"

Comment: App tools (save) vs developer tools (save-dev)

Comment: This answer is frustratingly vague. Even a small example would go a long way to helping make this clearer.

Comment: Note that as of npm version 5.0.0, the `--save` option is no longer necessary. If you do `npm install my-package`, it will add "my-package" as a dependency in the package.json file.

Comment: The problem with most highest rated answers to this question is that they fail to distinct server-side and frontend projects. In the latter case, you ship transpiled JS/CSS code, where all dependencies are "already included". You don't even need to upload `node_modules`. In such projects, you can safely `--save-dev` all your installed packages and be done with that.

Comment: React to new comers is already complicated, these answers mystify it further. Agreed with -pilat

Comment: A very important distinction: `--save` will install all of your dependencies whenever someone installs your package in their project.  If your dependencies are bundled in your output and only used in your build process, then use `--save-dev` (or `-D`).  Otherwise you are contributing to the monster that is node_modules

Answer (score 239):

By default, NPM simply installs a package under node_modules. When you're trying to install dependencies for your app/module, you would need to first install them, and then add them to the `dependencies` section of your `package.json`.

`--save-dev` adds the third-party package to the package's development dependencies. It won't be installed when someone runs `npm install` directly to install your package. It's typically only installed if someone **clones** your source repository first and then runs `npm install` in it.

`--save` adds the third-party package to the package's dependencies. It will be installed together with the package whenever someone runs `npm install package`.

Dev dependencies are those dependencies that are only needed for developing the package. That can include test runners, compilers, packagers, etc.
Both types of dependencies are stored in the package's `package.json` file. `--save` adds to `dependencies`, `--save-dev` adds to `devDependencies`

[npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install) documentation can be referred here.

--

**Please note** that `--save` is now the default option, since NPM 5. Therefore, it is not explicitly needed anymore. It is possible to run `npm install` without the `--save` to achieve the same result.

Comment: I suspected this... you can use --save-dev and --save interchangeably if you are build a web app that won't become a package i.e. downloaded from npm, if you are developing a package to share with others, it is important to understand the difference.

Comment: Thank you finally someone that says its purpose when you use npm install

Comment: --save is now default with npm install with the release of npm 5 in 2017

Comment: wait, why complex sentences? In DevDependecy developer can install the packages, and it will be updated the devDevependency only. So when new developer clone the project codebase and run npm install => here only `dependency package name is going to install.` in node_modules.. not developer's package as in Dev-dependency.

Comment: How is this not the top answer? Anyone with the ability to read can see that `--save-dev` is for development; the other answers are useless. This answer specifies how `--save` and `--save-dev` actually **behave differently**.

Answer (score 156):

Let me give you an example,

- You are a developer of a very **SERIOUS npm library** which uses different testing libraries to test the package.
- Users download your library and want to use it in their code. Do they need to download your testing libraries as well? Maybe you use `jest` for testing and they use `mocha`. Do you want them to install `jest` as well? *Just* To run your library?

No. right? That's why they are in `devDependencies`.

When someone does, `npm i yourPackage` only the libraries required to **RUN** your library will be installed. Other libraries you used to bundle your code with or testing and mocking will not be installed because you put them in `devDependencies`. Pretty neat right?

So, **Why** do the developers need to expose the **devDependancies**?

Let's say your package is an open-source package and 100s of people are sending pull requests to your package. Then how they will test the package? They will `git clone` your repo and when they would do an **`npm i`** the **dependencies** as well as **devDependencies**.
Because they are not using your package. They are developing the package further, thus, in order to test your package they need to pass the existing test cases as well write new. So, they need to use your `devDependencies` which contain all the testing/building/mocking libraries that YOU used.

Answer (score 82):

A perfect example of this is:

```
$ npm install typescript --save-dev
```

In this case, you'd want to have Typescript (a javascript-parseable coding language) available for development, but once the app is deployed, it is no longer necessary, as all of the code has been transpiled to javascript. As such, it would make no sense to include it in the published app. Indeed, it would only take up space and increase download times.

Comment: The same goes for:
"$ npm install grunt --save-dev",
as it is useful for development, but not for deployment.

Comment: A side note: Microsoft suggests installing @types/xxx packages as dependencies, not devDependencies https://github.com/Microsoft/types-publisher/issues/81

Comment: What I find confusing is how does this even matter? Packages saved using `--save` are still only saved in the `node_modules` folder. The code isn't included in the deployed website.

Comment: @Kokodoko When you use the `--save-dev` flag, the package is added to your `devDependencies` object. If/when someone installs **your** package, all the `dependencies` are downloaded but the `devDependencies` are not, since they aren't required at runtime. As the answer stated, this saves them time and space. Developers working on your package files itself can just run `npm install` inside the package directory to install the `devDependencies` as well.

Comment: So if you download a repo from github and type `npm install`, the `devDependencies` are ignored?

Comment: @JasjitSinghMarwah the best answer in this topic at all. The only one which explains practical difference not just that --save are in "dependencies": { } and --save-dev in "devDependencies": { } and that dev packages should by installed with --save-dev. So when my package is in the act not real npm package but website or app and I know that its source code will never be published in npm registry or will be never privately included by other packages it does not matter I use dependencies  or devDependencies.

Comment: @Kokodoko The other way around: `devDependencies` is ONLY installed when you download a repo from github and type `npm install`.

Answer (score 36):

As suggested by @andreas-hultgren in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19223182/1153783) and according to the [npm docs](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#devDependencies):

> If someone is planning on downloading and using your module in their program, then they probably don't want or need to download and build the external test or documentation framework that you use.

However, for webapp development, [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) (a scaffolding tool that installs a peer-reviewed, pre-written package.json file amongst other things) places all packages in devDependencies and nothing in dependencies, so it appears that the use of `--save-dev` is a safe bet in *webapp* development, at least.

Comment: Note that I've run into issues when using gulp and installing packages with `--save-dev` where the package would not install its required dependancies. Running `--save` installed those missing dependancies.

Comment: I'd also like to note that I'm now using `--save` for all but test and documentation dependencies (as per the npm docs). I'm beginning the think the Yeoman example I mentioned above is _not_ a good example of best practice.

Comment: I think so too, why would you ever need `--save-dev` is only becoming less clear with every answer here :)

Answer (score 26):

`--save-dev` saves semver spec into "devDependencies" array in your package descriptor file, `--save` saves it into "dependencies" instead.

Comment: and what's the functional difference?

Comment: this answer makes the most sense to me, devDependencies are then required for development but not production, so htmllint, sass compilation etc and Dependencies are for production requirements, such as Diaporama that will need to be present for things to run.

Comment: @ahnbizcad It's answered better [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875674/whats-the-difference-between-dependencies-devdependencies-and-peerdependencies) but the primary functional difference is that devDependencies are not transitively included.

Comment: Isn't the most intuitive way to describe it for someone who doesn't already know, this?: Dev `--save-dev` makes packages local to your project, whereas `--save` makes them local to your installation of node?

Answer (score 21):

`--save-dev` is used for modules used in development of the application,not require while running it in production environment
`--save` is used to add it in package.json and it is required for running of the application.

Example: express,body-parser,lodash,helmet,mysql all these are used while running the application use `--save` to put in dependencies while mocha,istanbul,chai,sonarqube-scanner all are used during development ,so put those in dev-dependencies .

npm link or npm install will also install the dev-dependency modules along with dependency modules in your project folder

Answer (score 18):

**Read Complete And Forget `--save-dev` Headache**

**Simplest answer** is that `--save-dev` is useful when you are creating **packages** for other **developers** and **want to host** your package at **NPM Registry** like **lodash, mongoose, express** etc. When you are building or writing a **Node Server** there is no difference between `--save` and `--save-dev` because your **Node Server** implementation is private to you and you will never publish it on **NPM**.

**How NPM Install Works**

Whenever we install a new package using **npm** like **npm install express** then **NPM** installs that package to our system and put it into **node_modules** folder, now **NPM** will analyze the **package.json** file of **newly installed** package i.e **express** in this case, after analyzing **NPM** will install all those packages which were mentioned in **dependencies** section of **package.json** file of **express** package. After installing those packages on which **express** was dependent **NPM** again **analyze** the **package.json** file of all **newly installed** packages and again install the packages for them, this cycle goes on until all packages are available into **node_modules** folder to function properly. You can check package dependencies by running **npm list** in terminal where terminal should point location of your **project directory**.

**How `--save-dev` Is Related To Above Explained Stuff**

Suppose you want to create a new **package** like **express**, now while development of this new package you probably want to write some **unit testing code** and test the package with any other available **testing package** let's assume **mocha** in this case. Now you know **mocha** is only required to **test the package** not required to **use the package**. In this case you should install **mocha** using `--save-dev` flag, otherwise **NPM** will install it whenever a developer install your package using **NPM**. So if we want a **dependency** not installed when someone install our package from **NPM** we must install that package using `--save-dev` in development phase.

**Last Thing**

Do not mix `--save-dev` with **collaboration development**, if someone cloned your package code from a source version control system like **github** then **NPM** will surely install all **devDependencies** i.e package installed using `--save-dev` also.

Answer (score 16):

When you install an npm package using `npm install <package-name>`, you are installing it as a dependency.

The package is automatically listed in the `package.json` file, under the `dependencies` list (as of npm 5: before you had to manually specify `--save`).
ex. `npm install lodash`
After pressing enter check your package.json file.

```
"dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.x",  
},
```

When you add the `-D` flag, or `--save-dev`, you are installing it as a development dependency, which adds it to the `devDependencies` list.

ex. `npm install --save-dev lite-server`
After pressing enter check your package.json file

```
"devDependencies": {
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1"
},
```

Development dependencies are intended as development-only packages, that are unneeded in production. For example testing packages, webpack, or Babel.

When you go in production, if you type `npm install` and the folder contains a `package.json` file, they are installed, as npm assumes this is a development deploy.

You need to set the `--production` flag (`npm install --production`) to avoid installing those development dependencies.

Answer (score 14):

Clear answers are already provided. But it's worth mentioning how `devDependencies` affects installing packages:

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json . With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production ), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies .

See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install

Answer (score 11):

All explanations here are great, but lacking a very important thing: How do you install production dependencies only? (without the development dependencies).
We separate `dependencies` from `devDependencies` by using `--save` or `--save-dev`.
To install all we use:

```sh
npm i
```

To install only production packages we should use:

```sh
npm i --only=production
```

Answer (score 10):

You generally don't want to bloat production package with things that you only intend to use for Development purposes.

Use `--save-dev` (or `-D`) option to separate packages such as Unit Test frameworks (jest, jasmine, mocha, chai, etc.)

Any other packages that your app needs for Production, should be installed using `--save` (or `-S`).

```
npm install --save lodash       //prod dependency
npm install -S moment           // "       "
npm install -S opentracing      // "       "

npm install -D jest                 //dev only dependency
npm install --save-dev typescript   //dev only dependency
```

If you open the `package.json` file then you will see these entries listed under two different sections:

```
"dependencies": {
  "lodash": "4.x",
  "moment": "2.x",
  "opentracing": "^0.14.1"
},

"devDependencies": {
    "jest": "22.x",
    "typescript": "^2.8.3"
},
```

Comment: I find this one of the clearest (simple and short) answers, but I’m still wondering what the functional difference really is. When I type `npm install`, both dependencies AND devDependencies get installed, so there doesn’t seem to be any difference?

Answer (score 9):

1. `--save-dev` (only used in the development, not in production)
2. `--save` (production dependencies)
3. `--global` or `-g` (used globally i.e can be used anywhere in our local system)

Answer (score 1):

People use npm on production to do wicked cool stuff, Node.js is an example of this, so you don't want all your dev tools being run.

If you are using gulp (or similar) to create build files to put on your server then it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

I want to add some of my ideas as

I think all differences will appear when someone uses your codes instead of using by yourself

For example, you write an HTTP library called `node's request`

In your library,

you used lodash to handle string and object, without lodash, your codes cannot run

If someone uses your HTTP library as a part of his code. Your codes will be compiled with his.

your codes need lodash, So you need to put in `dependencies` to **compile**

---

If you write a project like `monaco-editor`, which is a web editor,

you have bundled all your codes and your `product env library` using webpack, when build completed, only have a `monaco-min.js`

So someone doesn't care whether `--save` or `--save-dependencies`, only he needs is `monaco-min.js`

Summary:

1. If someone wants to compile your codes (use as a library),
   put `lodash` which used by your codes into `dependencies`
2. If someone want to add more feature to your codes, he needs `unit test` and `compiler`, put these into `dev-dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Basically We Write

```
npm install package_name
```

But specially for Testing Purpose we don't need to run some package while Application is Running in Normal State so that Node introduce good way to solve this problem. Whenever we write

```
npm install package_name --save-dev
```

at that time this package is only installed for development purpose.

Answer (score -1):

as --save is default option for npm, so I use

```
npm i package
```

and for --save-dev, I use

```
npm i package -D
```

default option will install package as project dependency where as -D is for development dependencies like testing, lint etc. and install package for development process

you can find all the flags here https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install

Comment: this doesn't explain what's the difference between them. This shouldn't be posted as an answer, but rather as a comment

Comment: YankovL, But he explained differences so this can be posted as answer