# Using globalize with webpack 2 and typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, typescript-typings, ts-loader, jquery-globalize

I am trying to use the [Globalize library](https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize) with [webpack 2](https://webpack.js.org/) in a TypeScript project.
The typescript/Webpack 2 setup already works, however, when importing and accessing Globalize, I am getting the following error message when running webpack:

```
ERROR in ./.tmp-globalize-webpack/C--Projects-webpack2-testing-app-index.ts
(1,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

ERROR in ./app/index.ts
(2,23): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'globalize'. 'C:\Projects\webpack2-testing\node_modules\globalize\dist\node-main.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

So I tried installing the globalize types:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/globalize
```

Now I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./.tmp-globalize-webpack/C--Projects-webpack2-testing-app-index.ts
(1,1): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'module'.

ERROR in ./app/index.ts
(2,23): error TS2306: File 'C:/Projects/webpack2-testing/node_modules/@types/globalize/index.d.ts' is not a module.
```

Unfotunately this is all very new to me. Don't know if I should check webpack or typings or globalize or typescript...

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "webpack2-testing",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack-config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cldr-data": "^30.0.4",
    "globalize": "^1.2.2",
    "globalize-webpack-plugin": "^0.3.10",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^2.1.6",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

and the index.ts:

```
import Globalize from "globalize";

function component () {
  let element = document.createElement('div');

  let currencyFormatter = Globalize.currencyFormatter( "USD" );
  element.innerHTML = currencyFormatter( 69900 );
  return element;
}

document.body.appendChild(component());
```

The complete project files (including webpack-config) are available at [this github repository](https://github.com/dominic-simplan/webpack2-testing).

Note: This question arose while trying to solve a [question I asked previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42208273/module-loader-for-typescript-application-running-locally-no-webserver-used). If this works, it could also resolve my previous question.

Comment: 1. index.ts is not a module, refer to: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html and 2. If you are manipulating the DOM you probably should do it inside of a DOMContentLoaded event listener https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Answer (score 2):

I did the following steps to use globalize.js in typescript project.

1.
Install the library

```
npm install globalize
npm install @types/globalize
```

2.
Create a file to export module
(globalize.d.ts)

```
/// <reference types='globalize' />

/* tslint:disable */

declare namespace globalize { }
declare module 'globalize' {
    export default Globalize;
}
```

3.
Use in my main file

```
import globalize from 'globalize';

// Formatter creation.
var formatter = globalize.numberFormatter();

// Formatter execution (roughly 10x faster than above).
formatter( Math.PI );
```

However, I never success download the cldr lib, so my browser has errors like:

```
./src/client/index.tsx
(5,23): error TS2306: File '/Users/alen/Workspace/Qunhe/core/node_modules/@types/globalize/index.d.ts' is not a module.
./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'cldr' in /Users/alen/Workspace/Qunhe/core/node_modules/globalize/dist
@ ./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js 22:2-25:14
./~/globalize/dist/globalize.js
```

I'm not sure it's the globalize.js issue or cldr.js issue, still trying.
Sorry I made the early reply other than solve your question.

**Edit:**

To solve the error above, I use the webpack plugin to help me pack data, and install the cldr-data. and it did works.

1. Add globalize-webpack-plugin 
   https://github.com/rxaviers/globalize-webpack-plugin

and use in webpack.config.js as demo illustrate here.
https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/tree/master/examples/app-npm-webpack

2. Install the cldr-data library, because this issue 
   https://github.com/globalizejs/globalize/issues/548

I have to install using

```
npm install globalize cldr-data
```

And back in browser, every thing works well.

[image]

Comment: I did this: npm install --save-dev @types/globalize (see question above). Do I have to skip the save-dev?

Comment: You should using npm install --save instead of --save-dev, because you'll using these lib in production anyway. You can refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-difference-between-save-and-save-dev

Comment: However I think it's not the issue cause your problem

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! The application now compiles with webpack, however I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'currencyFormatter' of undefined" in the browser.
Are you using webpack 2 or webpack 1? Do you maybe have your working project somehwere on github so I could compare?

Comment: I'll try make a demo on github this weekend.

Comment: @AlenLiang have you write that demo program you said you'll write on github  ?

Answer (score 2):

I finally got it to work:

1. In your `globalize.d.ts` file:

   ```
    declare module 'globalize' {
        export = Globalize;
    }
   ```
2. In your webpack config:

   ```
   plugins: [
       new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           Globalize: "globalize"
       })
   ]
   ```
3. And finally, when you import `globalize` in all your `.ts` files:

   ```
   import * as Globalize from 'globalize';
   ```