# node-sass installation issue on windows 10

Tags: node.js

I have installed node js latest version(8.8.1) and npm latest version(5.5.1)
and when i try to install node-sass i get this:

```
npm install -g node-sass
```

C:\Users\Giannis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node-sass -> C:\Users\Giannis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass\bin\node-sass

> node-sass@4.5.3 install C:\Users\Giannis\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\node-sass
>   node scripts/install.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.5.3 install: `node scripts/install.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.5.3 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Giannis\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2017-10-26T11_57_10_751Z-debug.log

I have set the system variable
 C:\Program Files\nodejs\

Thanks

Comment: Do you have [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows) installed ? [doc](https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install)

Comment: @GabrielBleu I get almost the same error when i try to install node-gyp...

Comment: Sometimes for global packages, running as administrator helps.

Comment: What's the output of `node --version` ?

Comment: @GabrielBleu I have run it as admin. same error... both in node-gyp and node-sass

NPM version : 5.3.0

Node version: v8.8.1

Node Platform: win32

Node architecture:x64

Comment: Did you typed `node --version` in a terminal ?

Comment: yes, one thing i noticed just now is when i open the windows cmd as administrator i can install it while with gitbash i cannot

Comment: Try restarting you gitbash terminal for the env variable to take affect.

Comment: @GabrielBleu once i install it with windows cmd then i can work with my gitbash. But for example if I download a project from github and then type npm install to install its dependencies then again gitbash does not work(with node-sass) so i have to do it again with the cmd. So any idea what is wrong with my gitbash?

Comment: Check your PATH, maybe add a .bashrc see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10681101/git-bash-doesnt-see-my-path

Comment: I fixed this on my machine and wrote about it in a [Github discussion](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1960#issuecomment-800962390)

Answer (score 63):

node-sass requires node-gyp https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install

node-gyp requires windows-build-tools https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's [windows-build-tools](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools) using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator).

Comment: I found it. I had to remove cygwin from enviroment variables. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer, I found this helpful. @GabrielBleu

Comment: Is there any way to use node-sass without the build tools on windows? I don't have administrator access to my machine so can't get windows-build-tools installed.

Comment: `windows-build-tools` doesn't work any more apparently. installation is stuck and many others complain the same on the github issues page :/

Comment: Any updates on this? ```windows-build-tools``` doesn't work anymore. Thought I found the answer but then stuck again.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` on an Elevated prompt works for me. The installer got stuck on visual studio build tools, but they were already installed on my system. So i `ctrl +c` the `npm install` process and run it once again. This time a messages shows up that the build tools are already installed and the installation will be skipped and continued with python configuration.

Finally the `node-sass` installation completed successfully.

BTW `node-sass` usage is deprecated and will be removed. The suggestion is to start using `sass`.

Answer (score -1):

2023 answer: Downgrade node from 20+ to 16.