# unable to start ioinc 3 project

Tags: node.js, ionic-framework, npm, sass

hi guys when i try to start an ionic 3 blank project, it keeps complaining of not being able to find sasss, this is the annoying error it keeps giving me.

also do you think it's wise for me to build a chatting app like whatsapp with ionic ?

- IONIC  DEVAPP  *

  Speed up development with the Ionic DevApp, our fast, on-device testing mobile app

  - Test on iOS and Android without Native SDKs
  - LiveReload for instant style and JS updates

> npm i
>   × Running command - failed!
>   [ERROR] An error occurred while running npm i (exit code 1):

```
 > node-sass@4.7.2 install C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-sass
        > node scripts/install.js

        Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node
        Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.7.2/win32-x64-64_binding.node":

        HTTP error 404 Not Found

        Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
               try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

               export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

        or configure npm proxy via

               npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

        > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall
        C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
        > node lib/post_install.js


        > node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-sass
        > node scripts/build.js

        Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
        C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose
        --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
        gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
        gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
        gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
        gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
        gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
        gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
        gyp info using node-gyp@3.7.0
        gyp info using node@10.2.1 | win32 | x64
        gyp verb command rebuild []
        gyp verb command clean []
        gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
        gyp verb command configure []
        gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
        gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
        gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at
        FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)',
        gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
        gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
        gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed  python { Error: not found: python
        gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at F
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at E
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
        gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
        gyp verb `which` failed   stack:
        gyp verb `which` failed    'Error: not found: python\n    at getNotFoundError
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E
        (C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at
        C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at
        FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)',
        gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
        gyp verb could not find "python". checking python launcher
        gyp verb could not find "python". guessing location
        gyp verb ensuring that file exists: C:\Python27\python.exe
        gyp ERR! configure error
        gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
        gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:492:19)
        gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous>
        (C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:517:16)
        gyp ERR! stack     at
        C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
        gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:182:21)
        gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
        gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe"
        "C:\\Users\\Djokhar-pc\\Documents\\Project\\trazeapp\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
        "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
        gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\Documents\Project\trazeapp\node_modules\node-sass
        gyp ERR! node -v v10.2.1
        gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.7.0
        gyp ERR! not ok
        Build failed with error code: 1
        npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
        npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted
        {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
        npm ERR! errno 1
        npm ERR! node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
        npm ERR! Exit status 1
        npm ERR!
        npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.7.2 postinstall script.
        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
        npm ERR!     C:\Users\Djokhar-pc\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-11T09_09_02_716Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this link could help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977724/6599076

> node-sass requires node-gyp https://github.com/sass/node-sass#install
>
> node-gyp requires windows-build-tools https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

Comment: should i install it globally or use --save-dev  ?

Comment: If you click the windows-build-tools link above it has instructions.  I'd suggestion option 1 from that link: "using `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as Administrator)."

Comment: still having the same issue. it's still failing