# Problem with starting a new project with Ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic3, npm-scripts

I am getting an error when I try to start a new project with Ionic.
I updated node and node-sass but it still doesn't work..

NPM version: 5.6.0

Node version: v8.11.4

OS: Windows 10

This is my full log file [https://gist.github.com/yordanzhelevdev/63045a43e7c56d2eb0dca6be3b4745dc][1]

How to fix that error?

```
$ ionic start IonicPlaygroud tutorial
√ Preparing directory .\IonicPlaygroud - done!
√ Downloading and extracting tutorial starter - done!
? Integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? Yes
> ionic integrations enable cordova --quiet
[INFO] Downloading integration cordova
[INFO] Copying integrations files to project
[OK] Integration cordova added!

> npm i
npm WARN deprecated hoek@2.16.3: The major version is no longer supported. Please update to 4.x or newer

> node-sass@4.9.0 install C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/install.js

Downloading binary from https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node
Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.0/win32-x64-57_binding.node":

ESOCKETTIMEDOUT

Hint: If github.com is not accessible in your location
      try setting a proxy via HTTP_PROXY, e.g.

      export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:1234

or configure npm proxy via

      npm config set proxy http://example.com:8080

> uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
> node lib/post_install.js


> node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\node-sass
> node scripts/build.js

Building: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js rebuild --verbose --libsass_ext= --libsass_cflags= --libsass_ldflags= --libsass_library=
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp verb cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
gyp verb cli   'C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js',
gyp verb cli   'rebuild',
gyp verb cli   '--verbose',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ext=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_cflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_ldflags=',
gyp verb cli   '--libsass_library=' ]
gyp info using node-gyp@3.8.0
gyp info using node@8.11.4 | win32 | x64
gyp verb command rebuild []
gyp verb command clean []
gyp verb clean removing "build" directory
gyp verb command configure []
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python2" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` failed Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed  python2 { Error: not found: python2
gyp verb `which` failed     at getNotFoundError (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:13:12)
gyp verb `which` failed     at F (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:68:19)
gyp verb `which` failed     at E (C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:80:29)
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\which\which.js:89:16
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\isexe\index.js:42:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\isexe\windows.js:36:5
gyp verb `which` failed     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp verb `which` failed   stack: 'Error: not found: python2\n    at getNotFoundError (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:13:12)\n    at F (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:68:19)\n    at E (C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:80:29)\n    at C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\which\\which.js:89:16\n
 at C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\isexe\\index.js:42:5\n    at C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\isexe\\windows.js:36:5\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)',
gyp verb `which` failed   code: 'ENOENT' }
gyp verb check python checking for Python executable "python" in the PATH
gyp verb `which` succeeded python C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Command failed: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.EXE -c import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack   File "<string>", line 1
gyp ERR! stack     import sys; print "%s.%s.%s" % sys.version_info[:3];
gyp ERR! stack                                ^
gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: invalid syntax
gyp ERR! stack
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\IonicPlaygroud\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--verbose" "--libsass_ext=" "--libsass_cflags=" "--libsass_ldflags=" "--libsass_library="
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\User\Desktop\IonicPlaygroud\node_modules\node-sass
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
Build failed with error code: 1
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.4 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.4: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall: `node scripts/build.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-sass@4.9.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-06T14_55_14_059Z-debug.log
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess npm.

        npm i exited with exit code 1.

        Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Have you seen this?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977724/6599076

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this link for some tips on node-sass and node-gyp on Windows:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46977724/6599076