# Node-Sass - win32-x64-57_binding.node not beeing able to download

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, meteor

I'm currently trying to get a program of an retired colleague working, but while trying to run

```
meteor run
```

I get this error.

```
   While loading package materialize:materialize@0.100.2:
   error: Command failed: C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.8.1\mt-os.windows.x86_64\dev_bundle\bin\npm.cmd rebuild --update-binary
   Cannot download "https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.5.2/win32-x64-57_binding.node": 
   
   HTTP error 404 Not Found
```

I've already tried

- manually installing it myself with another version
- deleting node_modules and package-lock.js

System

- node-v 8.5.1
- meteor-v 1.8.1

I've looked for the missing version of this and found this.
https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases?after=3.4.6
where the _57 is missing.

Comment: Can you please add the `package.json` dependencies / dev-dependencies and the `.meteor/packages` list?

Comment: There are a couple of these issues around here trying to install Sass on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45876943/node-sass-installation-issue?rq=1

Comment: First step would be to upgrade to at least Meteor v1.9 to be on Node 12. Best to go to at least 2.2.3 if possible.

Answer (score 0):

The node-sass release it is trying to download doesn't seem to exist anymore, see https://github.com/sass/node-sass/tags. Also, as StorytellerCZ already pointed out you need to use node 12 with meteor 1.8. Meteor usually does this automatically (it has it's own version of node), but on your system -- or maybe that's just a windows thing -- it still seems to try and use node 8, as can be seen from the `57` in the URL. This is the [node module version](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/) of node 8, node 12 has module version 72.

Since it seems that this is an old installation I would delete `C:\Users\felix\AppData\Local\.meteor` and reinstall meteor. You don't need to worry about installing the right version. Meteor always installs the latest version of the meteor tool itself on the system and then installs the correct version (even if older) for any project you try to run.