# npm ERR! missing script: build when deploying react app to heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment

I have a few small react web apps I have made that I am trying to deploy to heroku. I found this https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack through a youTube video and supposedly this is/was a simple method for deployment. There are several steps the author lists (first two don't apply):

1. git init
2. heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack
   https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack.git
3. git add .
4. git commit -m "Start with create-react-app"
5. git push heroku master
6. heroku open

Once I get to the git push heroku master I get an error in console that says:

```
npm ERR! missing script: build
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     /app/.npm/_logs/2018-03-26T16_55_19_748Z-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile React.js (create-react-app) multi app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to my-simple-react-weather-app.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/my-simple-react-weather-app.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/my-simple-react-weather-app.git'
```

I did some searching and found a few build scripts for my package.json file but none of them seem to work (""build": " webpack --config webpack.conf.js"")

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "redux-simple-starter",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Simple React YouTube App",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "test": "mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register --require ./test/test_helper.js --recursive ./test",
    "test:watch": "npm run test -- --watch"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chai-jquery": "^2.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.1",
    "jsdom": "^8.1.0",
    "mocha": "^2.4.5",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "^0.14.7",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "react-redux": "4.3.0",
    "react-router": "^2.0.1",
    "redux": "^3.0.4",
    "youtube-api-search": "0.0.5"
  }
}
```

Can anyone help me out here? I am logged into my heroku account already. Is there a simpler way than what I am doing here?

Comment: Can you share your `package.json` ?

Comment: I have updated my original post. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you provide a git repo it may help to git to the issue quickly but for now make sure you installed

react-scripts

```
npm i react-scripts --save-dev
```

make sure -dev is there so it runs before server launch [for more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-save-dev)

also, keep your client ( react app ) package.json including the same

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
```

also its very important to make sure you are using the right buildpacks
if its only react app no node.js [for more details](https://github.com/mars/create-react-app-buildpack)

```
heroku create $APP_NAME --buildpack mars/create-react-app
```

but if you are building dual with node.js

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

and consider to follow instructions here  [How to use create-react-app with a custom Node server on Heroku](https://github.com/mars/heroku-cra-node)

Answer (score 2):

You mentioned that `"build": " webpack --config webpack.conf.js"` is not working.  I am guessing that is why you omitted it from your `package.json`.  This is what is needed to resolve the error message.  Once you get this script working in your `package.json`, then all should be good.

Looking at the start script, it's possible that you need to run webpack by specifying it from the `.bin` directory.  I'm not sure what version of node you are using.

```
scripts: {
    ...
    "build": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack --config webpack.conf.js",
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
"build": "webpack"
```

This where I got it from.
https://webpack.js.org/guides/getting-started/