# angular cli Could not find module

Tags: angular

```
Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\College-Portal-master".
Error: Could not find module "@angular-devkit/build-angular" from "C:\\College-Portal-master".
    at Object.resolve (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\node\resolve.js:141:11)
    at Observable.rxjs_1.Observable [as _subscribe] (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect.js:132:40)
    at Observable._trySubscribe (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:44:25)
    at Observable.subscribe (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:30:22)
    at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:99:19
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Observable.toPromise (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\rxjs\internal\Observable.js:97:16)
    at ServeCommand.initialize (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:130:86)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
```

Comment: how about give some information?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You're not giving us enough informations to answer your question. Please read the guide on [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You probably did the installation steps correctly, but didn't install properly.

Check with `ng update` if you have the latest angular goods.

Check with `npm outdated` to see if some package is being annoying to you.

In the case you have a proxy, and it is not allowing the installation of some parts of the CLI, add the proxy to node with

```
npm config set proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.company.com:8080
```

In the case the problem was with git, install git.

In the case the problem is with dependencies, be sure to update them with `npm i @lacking-dependency`

Also, be sure to know the difference [between --save-dev and --save](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31358981/10121165)

Answer (score 0):

As it's quite clear from the error message, `@angular-devkit/build-angular` is not available in the installed node_modules.

Just run this:

```
npm install --save-dev @angular-devkit/build-angular
```

And you should be good.

Comment: who says he dosent have it installed?
maybe he just need to include it in the Angular module app?

Comment: @Talg123, Angular depends on `@angular-devkit/build-angular` to build the app before it could be served. It's not something that you generally add to the imports array of an `NgModule`.