# Does Webpack care if a dependency is installed using --save-dev

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

If I add React Router to my React app, and I use Webpack to bundle my code, does it matter if I install React Router using `--save-dev` or not?

This question is **not** about the difference between `--save` and `--save-dev`, but about whether `webpack` handles `devDependencies` differently.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between --save and --save-dev?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-save-dev)

Comment: What do you mean *"care"*? When Webpack bundles your app it resolves library imports in node_modules/, how they got there isn't relevant.

Comment: That's the thing, I know the difference between `--save` and `--save-dev`, but this is a different question. Will webpack exclude dependencies if they are installed using `--save-dev`? That's my question.

Comment: It would be relatively easy to test that out, no? Given that client build deps are generally not needed on a production server, I'd guess that *most* things Webpack ends up resolving and bundling are devDependencies.

Comment: webpack doesn’t care how a library got to the vendors directory as long as it’s there.

Comment: Most questions on this website are easy to test, if we add this question people will find an answer quickly in the future.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`webpack` does not care if a dependency is a `devDependency` or a regular `dependency`. [It simply includes all code that is imported by the files that are iterated when bundling](https://www.reddit.com/r/webpack/comments/7ouw5f/webpack_installing_devdependencies_vs/).

Comment: It depends on build mode

Comment: Could you elaborate? Will build mode `production` exclude all `devDependencies`?