# I'm trying to use enzyme in my React project for testing, but it throws this error: Cannot find module 'enzyme' from 'setupTests.js'

Tags: reactjs, testing

I already ran the command `npm install --save-dev @ wojtekmaj / enzyme-adapter-react-17` in my project.

Put this in my **setupTests.js** file:

```
import Enzyme from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from '@wojtekmaj/enzyme-adapter-react-17';

Enzyme.configure({ adapter: new Adapter() });
```

And when I start running the tests I get the error.

This is my test file:

**PrimeraApp.test.js**

```
import React from "react";
import PrimeraApp from "../PrimeraApp";
import { shallow } from "enzyme";

describe("PrimeraApp.js", () => {
  test("Debe mostrar <PrimeraApp /> correctamente", () => {
    const saludo = "Hola mundo";
    const wrapper = shallow(<PrimeraApp saludo={saludo} />);

    expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

If you can help me, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install enzyme package as well.
npm i --save enzyme

Comment: You probably want `--save-dev` rather than `--save` for a testing library. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/