# npm install cypress vs npm install cypress --save-dev

Tags: npm

Iam new to cypress wanted to know what is difference between `npm install cypress` vs `npm install cypress --save-dev`  I googled but not finding any answers

Comment: See [this related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22891211/what-is-the-difference-between-save-and-save-dev?answertab=votes#tab-top) that describes the differences between the `--save` and `--save-dev` options. Note the `--save` option that is mentioned in that post is no longer necessary (_in earlier npm versions it was)_. You can now consider `npm install cypress` to be the same as `npm install cypress --save`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between these two, is that devDependencies are modules which are only required during development, while dependencies are modules which are also required at runtime. [src](https://medium.com/@dylanavery720/npmmmm-1-dev-dependencies-dependencies-8931c2583b0c#:%7E:text=The%20difference%20between%20these%20two,an%20npm%20install%20%2D%2Dsave)

Modules like Mochajs, cypress, jsdoc, etc are devDependencies, because they are useful just in develop Env and in Production Env We don't need them.

There are at least 2 different envs while developing, somewhere you develop and code and do some tests on your code(**develop** Env) and somewhere you deliver your product to your customer, which means you have tested your code completely and there is no need to run tests again(**product**).

You need some modules like cypress and mocha just for testing. In product env you don't need to test the product again. So you don't install extra modules!

So you need something like `devDependencies` in package manager to handle it for you.

Comment: Saeed --Much thanks what do you mean by during development here is it dev environment >? ? Iam running my cypress automation testcases  so here will I will be using dependencies or devdependencies can you please help

Comment: I update my answer, Hope it helps. @sumitgoyal

Comment: What if I use only dependencies word ?? what is difference then please tell

Comment: You can install all your modules as dependency and not devDependency, the only difference is the packages you have to install while you're using that. But one of the good points of a module is the number of dependencies. Less dependencies means better. @sumitgoyal

Answer (score 2):

With `npm install cypress`, you are just installing cypress. with `npm install --save-dev` you are installing it as a dev dependency.

Comment: --Much thanks what do you mean by during development here is it dev environment ?? ? Iam running my cypress automation testcases  so here will I will be using dependencies or devdependencies can you please help

Answer (score 0):

With the command `npm install cypress` you are installing the latest version of cypress in your system and you have to give this command through vs code terminal.